# MX Player Subtitles Settings not working on videos with SSA subtitles

Tags: applications, settings, video, media-player, mx-player

I had my MX player's subtitle settings working just fine on all videos without bias. Recently I had to uninstall my MX player and reinstall it. After that, I tried to change the subtitle settings by changing the text size and text color. However, not all videos are taking this change into effect. The videos which have SSA subtitles are not taking any kind of modifications in how the subtitles are displayed and showing the default white colored subtitles with default text size. But earlier, before reinstalling, the same videos used to have these customized subtitle settings which I put into effect.

I have tried newer and older versions of MX player but the problem persists.